# How to make sure that dependency injection is working properly via TestCase

Tags: php, laravel-5, dependency-injection

**Provider**

```
namespace App\Providers;


class ElasticSearchProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $hosts = [
            'elasticsearch'
        ];
        $instance =  Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
                        ->setHosts($hosts)
                        ->build();

        $this->app->instance('App\ESClient', $instance);
    }
}
```

**Actual Class**

namespace App\Mappings;

```
class Categories implements Mappable
{
    public $es;

    public function __construct(App\ESClient $es)
    {
        $this->es = $es;
    }

    public function setMapping()
    {

    }

    public function getMapping()
    {

    }
}
```

**Test Case**

```
use App\Mappings\Categories;

class CategoriesTest extends TestCase
{
    private $instance;

    public function testShouldReturnElasticSearchInstance()
    {
        $categories = new Categories();
        dd($categories->es);
    }
}
```

> 1) CategoriesTest::testShouldReturnElasticSearchInstance
>   ErrorException: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Mappings\Categories::__construct() must be an instance of
>   App\Mappings\App\ESClient, none given,

So in here DI is not working, or i have register something wrong how can we test it ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, your public "function __construct(App\ESClient $es)" accepts App\ESClient, while in the test "$categories = new Categories();" you do not provide anything. Send App\ESClient variable there as a parameter

Comment: That is my question, I expect Laravel to inject this dependency

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) for test case. So in this example your test case would looks like:

```
use App\ESClient;
use App\Mappings\Categories;
use Mockery as m;

class CategoriesTest extends TestCase
{
    private $instance;

    public function testShouldReturnElasticSearchInstance()
    {
        $esClient = m::mock(ESClient::class);
        $categories = m::mock(new Categories($esClient));
        dd($categories->es);
    }
}
```

This will provides you a mocked class of `App\ESClient` that you will inject into partialy mocked class of `App\Mappings\Categories`. When you learn to use mockery in your unit test you will find that this is the best opion for test purpose - because mock object (and Laravel Facades) can be override while testing and can catch every method call of the object in test (with `shouldReceive` method of the mocked class).